# How to DRY up this RSpec controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I DRY this spec up?

```
describe Api::TasksController, type: :controller do
  it 'allows the creator of a task to destroy it' do
    set_request_auth_header @user
    delete :destroy, id: @task.id
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(Task.count).to eq 0
  end

  it 'does not allow the assignee of a task to destroy it' do
    set_request_auth_header @assignee
    delete :destroy, id: @task.id
    expect(response).to be_forbidden
    expect(Task.count).to eq 1
  end

  it 'does not allow anyone unrelated to a task to destroy it' do
    set_request_auth_header @spy
    delete :destroy, id: @task.id
    expect(response).to be_forbidden
    expect(Task.count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this Code Review would be a more appropriate site for this one: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know this site! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract some methods:

```
describe Api::TasksController, type: :controller do
  it 'allows the creator of a task to destroy it' do
    expect_delete_to_succeed @user
  end

  it 'does not allow the assignee of a task to destroy it' do
    expect_delete_to_be_forbidden @assignee
  end

  it 'does not allow anyone unrelated to a task to destroy it' do
    expect_delete_to_be_forbidden @spy
  end

  def expect_delete_to_succeed(requester)
    delete_task requester
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(Task.count).to eq 0
  end

  def expect_delete_to_be_forbidden(requester)
    delete_task requester
    expect(response).to be_forbidden
    expect(Task.count).to eq 1
  end

  def delete_task(requester)
    set_request_auth_header requester
    delete :destroy, id: @task.id
  end

end
```

Side notes:

- Using instance (@) variables is not current standard practice in RSpec. Look into [`let` 'variables'](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).
- `Task.exists? @task.id` seems like a clearer way of checking the deletion than checking `Task.count`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hopping there was some DSL-like way to achieve this, perhaps using shared_examples or something like that.

Comment: Thanks anyway :)

Just for the record, I wanted to be more concise on my question (removing the "I think it is a silly question" but SO wouldn't allow me to post it without more text :(

Comment: I answered since I think Ruby methods often do a better (more readable, less mysterious) job of DRYing up specs than RSpec features. Shared examples and such quickly get hard to follow. Didn't know that about questions; I'll have to experiment sometime.

Comment: i don't think that this makes it more dry. it adds more lines of code and it makes it harder to understand because of the unnecessary indirection.

Comment: It unquestionably has less duplication (DRY), which is what was asked. Whether it's easier to understand than the original, now, that's a different question. I'm not sure I'd do this if I only had these three tests. I'd definitely do it if I had 8 or 10. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

you don't. voila, you are welcome.